# Google adsense stats plugin?

Tags: plugins, dashboard, adsense, google

Does anyone know if there's a WP plugin that shows you stats about your ads (like clicks, earnings, etc) ? I've been looking around and most plugins I've found only let's you manage the actual ad code.

I found [this one](http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Modules/WordPress-Plugins/Adsense-Stats-54781.html) but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably [Wordpress Ad-Manager](http://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-admanager/544421?WT.ac=search_item&ref=straightforward&WT.seg_1=search_item&WT.z_author=Geardev) plugin will help you. Pay attention that the plugin is not free, but it provides information that you need and makes even more.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this one: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-adsense-dashboard-for-wp/

Works perfectly.